# Hacker News API - Get the most popular items

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, algolia, hacker-news-api

I stumbled upon Hacker News API (https://hn.algolia.com/api) and I was wondering if I am missing how to get the list of the most popular stories featured in the homepage.
Is there another API to do this or should I just implement a crawler myself to get it manually?

Answer (score 0):

This API indeed does not let you scan the **front page**, possibly because it is changing too often and **HNews** is known for setting rigorous limits to crawlers on the amount of requests they can make.

Alternatively I saw many HN aggregators focusing around *Posts with more than X points*, and this API allows you to do the same, example:

[https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?tags=story&numericFilters=points>100](https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?tags=story&numericFilters=points%3E100)

Otherwise I afraid you have to make your own crawler, which would request front-page frequently or on-demand, just make sure it is within limits. There was a discussion on HN on this subject, but I cannot find out right now.